# Using R to Analyze Balance Sheets and Income Statements

Tags: r, finance

I am interested in analyzing balance sheets and income statements using R. I have seen that there are R packages that pull information from Yahoo and Google Finance, but all the examples I have seen concern historical stock price information. Is there a way I can pull historical information from balance sheets and income statements using R?

Comment: Please consider voting for the quantitative finance stackexchange site idea here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/proposal-for-quantitative-finance-stackexchange-site.

Comment: Balance Sheet and Income Statement are not available from Yahoo or Google but freely from the SEC.GOV Edgar (https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/). There is a node package called parse-xbrl which will parsed the XBLR Instance File from Edgar and another node package r-script which you can use the quantmod R package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the common mistake of confusing 'access to Yahoo or Google data' with 'everything I see on Yahoo or Google Finance can be downloaded'.

When R functions download historical stock price data, they almost always access an interface explicitly designed for this purpose as e.g. a cgi handler providing csv files given a stock symbol and start and end date.  So this *easy* as all we need to do is form the appropriate query, hit the webserver, fetch the csv file an dparse it.

Now balance sheet information is (as far as I know) not available in such an interface. So you will need to 'screen scrape' and parse the html directly.

It is not clear that R is the best tool for this. I am aware of some Perl modules for the purpose of getting non-time-series data off Yahoo Finance but have not used them.

Comment: Thanks for a really quick answer Dirk. On checking further, I found that the package 'quantmod' has a function called 'getFinancials' and the manual for quantmod specifies its function as: 'Download Income Statement, Balance Sheet, and Cash Flow Statements from Google Finance.'

Now I tried it, but it returned a cryptic error (subscript out of bounds). Now does this mean that quantmod can scrape financials from google finance, but i am just making an error, or such functionality cannot exist? Any clarifications would be welcome.

Thanks once again!

Comment: Ok, so then it seems the package quantmod attempts to screen scrape and may have failed.

A reproducible report of what you tried and what error you got is something you could send to r-sig-finance where the package maintainer will see it.

Comment: Putting it out there: getFinancials/ viewFinancials no longer retrieves financial data from Google Finance:

https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221

Comment: Sure. You commented on an answer from April 2010. Sometimes things change, and free resources disappear.  Such is life.

Answer (score 10):

I have found on the net only a partial solution to your issue, for I managed to retrieve only the Balance sheet info and financial statement for one year. I don't know how to do it for more years.
There is a package in R, called **quantmod**, which you can install from CRAN

```
install.packages('quantmod')
```

Then you can do the following: Suppose you want to get the financial info from a company listed at NYSE : General Electric. ticker: GE

```
 library(quantmod)
 getFinancials('GE')
 viewFinancials(GE.f)
```

To get only the income statement, reported anually, as a data frame use this:

```
viewFinancials(GE.f, "IS", "A")
```

Please let me know if you find out how to do this for multiple years.

Comment: Worked for me! For more info:

http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getFinancials.html

Comment: @moldovean, thanks! :) this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @moldovean, Google Finance no longer provides data for historical prices or financial statements. https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221

Comment: this stopped working in 2018, I want to get financial statements, what package should I use, tidyquant, quantmod, quandl?

Answer (score 4):

The question you want to ask, and get an answer to!, is where can I get free XBRL data for analysing corporate balance sheets, and is there a library for consuming such data in R?

XBRL (Extensible Business Reporting Language - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL) is a standard for marking up accounting statments (income statements, balance sheets, profit & loss statements) in XML format such that they can easily be parsed by computer and put into a spreadsheet.

As far as I know, a lot of corporate regulators (e.g. the SEC in the US, ASIC in Australia) are encouraging the companies under their jurisdiction to report using such a format, or running pilots, but I don't believe it has been mandated at this point. If you limited your investment universe (I am assuming you want this data in electronic format for investment purposes) to firms that have made their quarterly reports freely available in XBRL form, I expect you will have a pretty short list of firms to invest in!

Bloomberg, Reuters et al all have pricey feeds for obtaining corporate fundamental data. There may also be someone out there running a tidy business publishing balance sheets in XBRL format. Cheaper, but still paid for, are XIgnite's [xFundamentals](http://www.xignite.com/xFundamentals.asmx) and [xGlobalFundamentals](http://www.xignite.com/xGlobalFundamentals.asmx) web services, but you aren't getting full balance sheet data from them.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I am interested in the statements for Research and not for Investments. I have access to Compustat, so data access is not a problem. But to my knowledge, Compustat does not have a Web API that I can use to directly pull data into R, and hence my interest in public sources.

Answer (score 3):

to read-in the financial information try this function ( I picked it up several months ago and made some small adjustments)

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)

getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
    measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

    #Clean up the column name
    measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

    #Remove dups
    dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
    #print(dups) 
    for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
      measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

    #use siblings function to get value
    values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

    df <- data.frame(t(values))
    colnames(df) <- measures
    return(df)
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

to use it, compare for example 3 companies and write the data into a csv-file do the following:

```
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG","F")
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```

Just tried it. Still working.

UPDATE as Yahoo changed it’s web site layout:

The function above does not work anymore as Yahoo again changed its web site layout. Fortunately its still easy to get the financial infos as the tags for getting fundamental data have not been changed. 
example for downloading a file with eps and P/E ratio for MSFT, AAPL and Ford insert the following into your browser:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT+AAPL+F&f=ser
```

and after entering the above URL into your browser’s address bar and hitting return/enter. The CSV will be automatically downloaded to your computer and you should get the cvs file as shown below (data as 7/22/2016):

[image]

some yahoo tags for fundamental data:

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me.. I'm thinking yahoo changed something

Comment: How do i get the entire Balance Sheet from yahoo? Is there a complete list of tags somewhere?

Comment: @Canadian_Republican, you can find a recent list of available tags at `http://www.marketindex.com.au/yahoo-finance-api#` but from what I know you can only get selected items. To get whole balance sheets or income statement SEC's Edgar service let you download balance sheets/income sheets in excel format for free. Go to `https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html`. There are many R-packages available which let you import Excel data.

Comment: excellent that list provides me with most of the info I need, and Quantmod gives me the rest

Comment: how can one get the reccomendations rating, or at least the css?

Comment: Excellent post! Is there a way to get the values from the analysts reccomendations and the analyst price target (average/ current)? I can not find the tags for getting them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the last two comments into consideration, you may be able to acquire corporate financial statements economically using EdgardOnline.  It isn't free, but is less expensive than Bloomberg and Reuters.  Another thing to consider is financial reporting normalization/standardized. Just because two companies are in the same industry and sell similar products does not necessarily mean that if you laid the two companies' income statements or balance sheets side by side, that reporting items would necessarily line up.  Compustat has normalized/standardized financial reports.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about R, but assuming that it can call a REST API and consume data in XML form, you can try the Mergent Company Fundamentals API at http://www.mergent.com/servius/ - there's lots of very detailed financial statement data (balance sheets / income statements / cashflow statements / ratios), standardized across companies, going back more than 20 years

Answer (score 1):

I have written a C# program that I think does what you want.  It parses the html from nasdaq.com pages.  It parses html and creates 1 csv file per stock that includes income statement, cash flow, and balance sheet values going back 5 - 10 years depending on the age of the stock.  I am now working to add some analysis calculations (mostly historic ratios at this point).  I'm interested in learning about R and it's applications to fundamental analysis.  Maybe we can help each other.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found this R package on CRAN.  Which does exactly what you are asking I believe.

[XBRL: Extraction of business financial information from XBRL documents](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XBRL/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all three types of financial statements from [Intrinio](http://intrinio.com) in R for free. Additionally, you can get as reported statements and standardized statements. The problem with pulling XBRL filings from the SEC is that there is no standardized option, which means you have to manually map financial statement items if you want to do cross equity comparisons. Here is an example:

```
#Install httr, which you need to request data via API
install.packages("httr")
require("httr")

#Install jsonlite which parses JSON
install.packages("jsonlite")
require("jsonlite")

#Create variables for your usename and password, get those at intrinio.com/login
username <- "Your_API_Username"
password <- "Your_API_Password"

#Making an api call for roic. This puts together the different parts of the API call

base <- "https://api.intrinio.com/"
endpoint <- "financials/"
type <- "standardized"
stock <- "YUM"
statement <- "income_statement"
fiscal_period <- "Q2"
fiscal_year <- "2015"

#Pasting them together to make the API call
call1 <- paste(base,endpoint,type,"?","identifier","=", stock, "&","statement","=",statement,"&","fiscal_period",
               "=", fiscal_period, "&", "fiscal_year", "=", fiscal_year, sep="")

# call1 Looks like this "https://api.intrinio.com/financials/standardized?identifier=YUM&statement=income_statement&fiscal_period=Q2&fiscal_year=2015"

#Now we use the API call to request the data from Intrinio's database

YUM_Income <- GET(call1, authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))

#That gives us the ROIC value, but it isn't in a good format so we parse it

test1 <- unlist(content(YUM_Income, "text"))

#Convert from JSON to flattened list

parsed_statement <- fromJSON(test1)

#Then make your data frame:

df1 <- data.frame(parsed_statement)
```

[image: The resulting data frame]

I wrote this script to make it easy to change out the ticker, dates, and statement type so you can get the financial statement for any US company for any period.

Comment: This looked very promising, but it appears that they no longer provide the data for free. It's $40/month or $400/year. https://intrinio.com/data/us-fundamentals-financials-metrics-ratios-stock-prices

Answer (score 0):

I actually do this in Google Sheets. I thought it to be the easiest way to do it as well and because it can pull real live data was another bonus point. Lastly it doesn't consume any of my space to save these statements.

=importhtml("http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/stock-income-statement/?symbol=US%3A"&B1&"&stmtView=Ann", "table",0)

where B1 cell contains the ticker.

You can do the same thing for balance sheet, and cash flow as well.

Answer (score 0):

1- Subscribe into yahoo finance api from Rapid Api [here](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1)

2- Get your key

3- Insert your key in the code:

```r
name="AAPL"
{raw=httr::GET(paste("https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com//api/yahoo/qu/quote/",name,"/financial-data", sep = ""),
        httr::add_headers("x-rapidapi-host"= "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
                    "x-rapidapi-key"="insert your Key here")
)
raw=jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(raw$content))
values=sapply(1:length(raw$financialData),function(x){sapply(raw, "[", x)[[1]][1]})
names(values)=names(raw$financialData)
values=as.data.frame(t(values))
row.names(values)=name
}
values
```

Pros: Easy way to get data

Cons: free version limited into 500 request per month