# Programmatically download ROIC and other financial data in R

Tags: r, stock

Is there some place I can programmatically download the ROIC and other data typically reported in a company's quarter report?

I know that I can access the daily price data of a stock from http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv, but I can't find anything about the financial performance.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at my [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614767/using-r-to-analyze-balance-sheets-and-income-statements/15975391#15975391) concerning downloads of balance sheets / income sheets data from Yahoo.

Comment: There is also [`quantmod::getFinancials`](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getFinancials.html).

Comment: Awesome. I knew about quantmod but didn't know they have a function to get the financial info.

Answer (score 1):

[Intrinio](http://intrinio.com) provides that data in R using the httr package. You can follow the [instructions here](http://blog.intrinio.com/intrinio-financial-data-in-r-and-rstudio/), I'll modify them here to get ROIC:

```
#Install httr, which you need to request data via API
install.packages("httr")
require("httr")

#Create variables for your usename and password, get those at intrinio.com/login
username <- "Your_API_Username"
password <- "Your_API_Password"

#Making an api call for roic. This puts together the different parts of the API call

base <- "https://api.intrinio.com/"
endpoint <- "data_point"
stock <- "T"
item1 <- "roic"
call1 <- paste(base,endpoint,"?","ticker","=", stock, "&","item","=",item1, sep="")

#Now we use the API call to request the data from Intrinio's database

ATT_roic <- GET(call1, authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))

#That gives us the ROIC value, but it isn't in a good format so we parse it

test1 <- unlist(content(ATT_roic,"parsed"))

df <- data.frame(test1)
```

You can modify that code for any US ticker, and you can change roic out for hundreds of other financial metrics. If you want to pull historical roic, or roic for a specific date range, see the instructions I posted at the start of this answer.