# In R Studio how would I pull a specific piece of data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

In R studio I am currently using the package quantmod to pull yahoo finance data. I found quantmod because someone recommended on: [How to scrape key statistics from Yahoo! Finance with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980350/how-to-scrape-key-statistics-from-yahoo-finance-with-r) in place of scraping. I am trying to pull Book value per share (BVPS) data.

This could be directly with

`library(quantmod)`

`getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Book Value Per Share")))`

it throws this ERROR: Error in `[.data.frame`(sq, , "regularMarketTime") :
undefined columns selected

I could alternatively calculate it myself if I could pull book value and preferred stock but

`getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Book Value")))`

throws the same error. So I am at a lose of what to do. Are these errors with quantmod or should I just be learning how to pull from the website myself and not using quantmod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

If you try to call `Book Value` with an additional value, it is working. However, when you call only `Book Value`, the function is giving an error. You can post this bug to the package provider's GitHub. Here is the [link](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues)

The following producer might work for you for now.

```
getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Open","Book Value")))

>
              Trade Time   Open Book Value
AAPL 2021-04-30 16:00:04 131.78      4.146
```

I just requested additional `Open` price information. With that, API worked.

Comment: That is very curious! As I left out my other value out so not to keep it clean.

```getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Open","Book Value")))```


Does work for me but now what was work yesterday is not, sigh. Below is what was working, but now the "Earnings/Share" is throwing the error. I wonder if it is something to do with the markets being open or closed?

```getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c("Earnings/Share","Book Value")))```

The funny thing is git hub sent me help first, because I didn't want to report and issue that was me just being bad at programming.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I figured it out! I added "open" to what was misbehaving and it worked. I think it needs a time stamp to pull from or it wont work.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I think it is a bug or something. Because when you call for another single value, you can get them. For example, `getQuote("AAPL",what=yahooQF(c('Ask')))
` works. Anyhow, if my answer helped you, you can accept my answer.

Comment: You are probably correct. I will try to figure out a concise why to post the issue on git hub.