# Adjusting Yahoo Stock Data Web Scraping to Loop over Dates

Tags: r, web-scraping, stock

I am using a similar script to that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245464/web-scraping-of-key-stats-in-yahoo-finance-with-r). In short, a proxy issue (or something) makes the API time out. I am having to parse the web address for Yahoo Finance data instead of using quantmod to get historic stock data. Because yahoo finance only loads 100 rows, even if you set the date range to more than at, until you scroll down, I need to get this "for loop" to loop over a list of 100 days at a time that I created. The start dates are in an integer format that Yahoo Finance uses.

The following is an example df for the 100 day increments, and the list will change/grow. The list of securities is also being imported from a file and dynamically changes as well, but I provided "symbols" below as an example.

In the following, I would want dateGroup[1,1] and dateGroup[1,2] to instead automatically take the first rows values from dateGroup, followed by the second rows, etc - and then build a single dataframe with all values.

```
dateGroup <- data.frame(
    start = c(1509519600, 1518159600,1526799600,1535439600,1544079600),
    end = c(1518073200, 1526713200,1535353200,1543993200,1550732400)
)

for (s in symbols){
    url <- paste('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/',s, '/history?period1=',dateGroup[1,1],'&period2=',dateGroup[1,2],'&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d',sep="")
    webpage <- readLines(url,warn=FALSE)
    html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
    tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")
    assign(s, readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]], header=c("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Adj. Close","Volume")))

    df <- get(s)
    df['symbol'] <- s
    assign(s, df)
}

symboldatalist <- cbind(mget(symbols))
symboldata <- do.call(rbind, symboldatalist)

symboldata <- symboldata[, c(ncol(symboldata), 1:ncol(symboldata)-1)]

write.table(symboldata, "[Location], sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

A couple things I've tried. I attempted to create a matrix of urls and scrape those with the symbols along the top and the dates in columns 1 and 2. I also attempted to program a automatic scroll on the Yahoo Finance page but ran into the same error with it timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `mapply` or its non-simplified wrapper, `Map`, to iterate elementwise through the pairings of start and end dates and corresponding symbols. Also, avoid the use of `assign` and `get` and build list of data frames for final `rbind` at the end:

```
library(XML)
...
dateGroup <- data.frame(
    start = c(1509519600, 1518159600, 1526799600, 1535439600, 1544079600),
    end = c(1518073200, 1526713200, 1535353200, 1543993200, 1550732400)
)

# CROSS JOIN ALL SYMBOLS WITH EACH DATE PAIRING
dt_grp_sym <- merge(dateGroup, data.frame(symbols))

# DEFINED METHOD FOR HTML PROCESSING
proc_html <- function(sym, sd, ed) {    
    url <- paste0('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/', sym, '/history?period1=',
                  sd, '&period2=', ed, '&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
    print(url)

    webpage <- readLines(url, warn=FALSE)
    html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
    tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")

    html_df <- transform(readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]],
                                       header=c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low",
                                                "Close", "Adj. Close", "Volume")),
                         symbol = sym)
    return(html_df)
}

# ITERATE ELEMENTWISE THROUGH EVERY ROW of dt_grp_sym
df_list <- Map(proc_html, dt_grp_sym$symbols, dt_grp_sym$start, dt_grp_sym$end)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

---

To demonstrate using the Class 1 U.S. railroads:

```
symbols <- c("UNP", "CSX", "NSC", "CNI", "KSU")

dateGroup <- data.frame(
  start = c(1509519600, 1518159600, 1526799600, 1535439600, 1544079600),
  end = c(1518073200, 1526713200, 1535353200, 1543993200, 1550732400)
)    
dt_grp_sym <- merge(dateGroup, data.frame(symbols))

# CALLING SAME ABOVE FUNCTION
df_list <- with(dt_grp_sym, Map(proc_html, symbols, start, end))   
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

**Output**

```
by(final_df, final_df$symbol, head)

# final_df$symbol: CNI
#              Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj..Close    Volume symbol
# 998  Feb 08, 2018 76.08 76.16 74.11 74.45      72.79 1,508,100    CNI
# 999  Feb 07, 2018 76.86 77.23 76.01 76.17      74.48 1,645,400    CNI
# 1000 Feb 06, 2018 76.21 77.42 74.81 77.14      75.42 2,293,300    CNI
# 1001 Feb 05, 2018 78.00 78.70 77.12 77.17      75.45 1,711,000    CNI
# 1002 Feb 02, 2018 79.17 79.24 78.17 78.46      76.71 1,331,400    CNI
# 1003 Feb 01, 2018 79.91 80.54 79.24 79.82      78.04 1,231,500    CNI
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# final_df$symbol: CSX
#             Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj..Close     Volume symbol
# 333 Feb 08, 2018 52.91 53.16 50.46 50.47      49.80  7,798,100    CSX
# 334 Feb 07, 2018 53.38 54.36 52.94 52.97      52.26  6,496,200    CSX
# 335 Feb 06, 2018 51.27 54.00 50.12 53.82      53.10 10,563,700    CSX
# 336 Feb 05, 2018 54.89 55.04 51.96 51.99      51.30  9,070,200    CSX
# 337 Feb 02, 2018 56.19 56.35 55.20 55.25      54.51  9,275,800    CSX
# 338 Feb 01, 2018 56.10 57.10 56.04 56.58      55.83  4,079,100    CSX
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# final_df$symbol: KSU
#              Date   Open   High    Low  Close Adj..Close    Volume symbol
# 1330 Feb 08, 2018 107.17 107.64 103.50 103.53     102.15 1,434,600    KSU
# 1331 Feb 07, 2018 106.59 108.27 106.59 107.10     105.67 1,326,800    KSU
# 1332 Feb 06, 2018 103.11 108.02 102.07 107.32     105.89 1,459,400    KSU
# 1333 Feb 05, 2018 109.73 110.44 105.12 105.18     103.77 1,272,100    KSU
# 1334 Feb 02, 2018 112.06 112.85 110.03 110.15     108.68 1,051,900    KSU
# 1335 Feb 01, 2018 112.80 114.00 112.17 112.87     111.36 1,011,200    KSU
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# final_df$symbol: NSC
#             Date   Open   High    Low  Close Adj..Close    Volume symbol
# 665 Feb 08, 2018 142.62 143.27 136.87 136.89     134.22 2,657,200    NSC
# 666 Feb 07, 2018 142.09 144.45 141.37 142.68     139.89 1,464,500    NSC
# 667 Feb 06, 2018 136.99 143.45 134.55 143.05     140.26 2,455,000    NSC
# 668 Feb 05, 2018 144.74 146.73 138.18 138.61     135.90 2,508,900    NSC
# 669 Feb 02, 2018 147.15 147.85 144.61 145.03     142.20 1,774,600    NSC
# 670 Feb 01, 2018 149.28 150.35 147.90 148.47     145.57 1,427,000    NSC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# final_df$symbol: UNP
#           Date   Open   High    Low  Close Adj..Close     Volume symbol
# 1 Feb 08, 2018 128.70 128.70 124.81 124.86     122.27  6,325,100    UNP
# 2 Feb 07, 2018 130.34 131.82 128.94 128.96     126.29  5,053,000    UNP
# 3 Feb 06, 2018 122.28 131.50 121.50 131.15     128.43 15,734,300    UNP
# 4 Feb 05, 2018 128.59 131.78 124.13 124.14     121.57  6,744,400    UNP
# 5 Feb 02, 2018 131.66 131.73 127.22 129.36     126.68  8,181,200    UNP
# 6 Feb 01, 2018 132.51 133.74 131.86 132.38     129.64  5,597,600    UNP
```