# Get Financial Statements from Yahoo Finance in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, tidyquant

I want to get Income Statement, Balance Sheet, and Cashflow statement from yahoo finance on companys. I know There is `Tidyquant`, but I didn't see options to pull this data. Is there other R packages that have an API to get this data? My last resort would be to webscrape the page, but was hoping there is an R package that uses the API? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614767/using-r-to-analyze-balance-sheets-and-income-statements#7636139) I actually want the package `quantmod`